# Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table

Tags: ssis

```
select
   FiscalMonthID = (select FiscalMonthID from CurrentFiscalMonth (nolock)),
   T.OrgKey,
   DataSourceKey = 26,
   OrganizationTypeKey = 2,
   SourceSystemID = MAX(T.MbsId),
   WEGFlag = convert(bit,0),
   D.CreateDT,
   D.CreateBy,
   D.UpdateDT,
   D.UpdateBy

from WorkDB.dbo.TempMbsOrgMap (nolock) as T
join WorkDB.dbo.MBSOrganization_Denorm2 (nolock) as D
      on T.MbsId = D.OrganizationID
--where OrgKey not in (select OrgKey from OrgMap where FiscalMonthID=258 and DataSourceKey=26 and OrganizationTypeKey=2)
group by
   T.OrgKey,
   D.CreateDT,
   D.CreateBy,
   D.UpdateDT,
   D.UpdateBy
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: And **please** - explain what your problem is, show us an error code, tell us what you're trying to do..... just staring at a SELECT statement without any further information isn't very productive, and you won't get much help that way......

Answer (score 12):

I don't know whether this person ever got the problem resolved.  If anyone else hits this error, the most helpful article I have found so far is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/executing-bcp-fails-with-sqlstate-37000-nativeerror-4891-error-microsoftodbc-sql-server-driversql-serverinsert-bulk-failed-due-to-a-schema-change-of-the-target-table

The recommendations from the article (it's worth reading the whole thing though) are as follows:

> Below is some of the action plan you can try, this helped in my case
> though.
>
> 1. Drop the Constraints before the BCP run and recreate them after the
>    run
> 2. Disable the Auto update stats (To isolate the issue)
> 3. Check if any parallel index rebuilds happening.
>
> If still the issue persists after implementing the above change,
> collect the Profiler trace to capture the activity when bcp is failing
> to further investigation.

Comment: updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/executing-bcp-fails-with-sqlstate-37000-nativeerror-4891-error-microsoftodbc-sql-server-driversql-serverinsert-bulk-failed-due-to-a-schema-change-of-the-target-table